# преобразование multipart/form-data в словарь

Tags: python, multipart

Можно ли как-нибудь преобразовать это:

```
-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sessionID"

596a2f350ffccdcab68e5408
-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="type"

profileSave
-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="weblink_1_title"


-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="weblink_1_url"


-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="weblink_2_title"


-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="weblink_2_url"


-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="weblink_3_title"


-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="weblink_3_url"


-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="personaName"

name
-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="real_name"


-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="customURL"

url
-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="country"

RU
-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="state"


-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="city"


-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="summary"

dsgsdfg
-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="type"

profileSave
-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sessionID"

596a2f350ffccdcab68e6308
-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"

1
-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671--
```

в словарь такого типа:

```
{
    "sessionID": (None, "596a2f350ffccdcab68e5408"),
    "type": (None, "profileSave"),
    и так далее...
}
```

Comment: "это" какого типа? строка?

Comment: А зачем здесь кортеж и None? А вообще есть [cgi.parse_multipart](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgi.html#cgi.parse_multipart) например

Comment: @andreymal None на этом месте это имя файла для отправки мультипарта в атрибуте files

Answer (score 1):

```
import cgi
import io

body="""-----------------------------33331565381703838529424543671
....
"""

stream = io.BytesIO(body.encode())
params = {'boundary':b'---------------------------33331565381703838529424543671'}
# boundary брать из хидера, на два минуса меньше чем в теле.

cgi.parse_multipart(stream, params)
```

Выход

```
{
  "weblink_2_title":[""],
  "real_name":[""],
  "personaName":["name"],
  "city":[""],
  "state":[""],
  "weblink_2_url":[""],
  "weblink_1_title":[""],
  "country":["RU"],
  "weblink_1_url":[""],
  "type":[
    "profileSave",
    "profileSave"
  ],
  "weblink_3_title":[""],
  "summary":["dsgsdfg"],
  "json":["1"],
  "weblink_3_url":[""],
  "customURL":["url"],
  "sessionID":[
    "596a2f350ffccdcab68e5408",
    "596a2f350ffccdcab68e6308"
  ]
}
```

Теряет последовательность ответов... Для последовательного чтения лучше загонять в [FieldStorage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgi.html#cgi.FieldStorage.getlist) напрямую, как это делается в [parse_multipart](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b745a6143ae79efe00aa46affe5ea31a06b0b532/Lib/cgi.py#L184) без последней команды.

```
headers = cgi.Message()
h.set_type('multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------33331565381703838529424543671')

fs=cgi.FieldStorage(stream, keep_blank_values=True, headers=headers, environ={'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST'})
```

Все поля, с которыми можно работать [в другом вашем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1234354/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-post-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-requests-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-multipart-form-data-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1) получаются так

```
files = [(field.name,(field.filename,field.value))  for field in fs.value]
```

Ответ на этот вопрос:

```
dict(files)
```