# Как с помощью POST запроса через requests передать multipart/form-data так, чтобы ключи словаря могли дублироваться?

Tags: python, requests, formdata, multipart

В этом тексте есть одинаковые ключи, для того, чтобы составить словарь для повторения запроса с помощью requests, но python не поддерживает дублирования ключей.

Пробовал удалить лишние ключи, чтобы остался один. Ничего не вышло.

Как быть?

*Исходный запрос:*

```
-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profile_showcase[]"

8
-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profile_showcase_purchaseid[]"

0
-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[8_0][0][title]"

1
-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[8_0][0][notes]"

1
-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profile_showcase[]"

0
-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profile_showcase_purchaseid[]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[4_0][6][notes]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[5_0][0][badgeid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[5_0][0][appid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[5_0][0][border_color]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[5_0][1][badgeid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[5_0][1][appid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[5_0][1][border_color]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[5_0][2][badgeid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[5_0][2][appid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[5_0][2][border_color]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[5_0][3][badgeid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[5_0][3][appid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[5_0][3][border_color]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[5_0][4][badgeid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[5_0][4][appid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[5_0][4][border_color]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[5_0][5][badgeid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[5_0][5][appid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[5_0][5][border_color]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[6_0][0][appid]"

730
-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[7_0][0][publishedfileid]"

1388791173
-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[7_0][1][publishedfileid]"

1442038664
-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[7_0][2][publishedfileid]"

1497191984
-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[7_0][3][publishedfileid]"

1442036684
-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[9_0][0][accountid]"

30357047
-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[10_0][0][appid]"

730
-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[11_0][0][appid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[11_0][0][publishedfileid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[12_0][0][appid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[12_0][0][publishedfileid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[12_0][1][appid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[12_0][1][publishedfileid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[12_0][2][appid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[12_0][2][publishedfileid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[12_0][3][appid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[12_0][3][publishedfileid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[12_0][4][appid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[12_0][4][publishedfileid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[14_0][0][publishedfileid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[14_0][1][publishedfileid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[14_0][2][publishedfileid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[14_0][3][publishedfileid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[15_0][0][appid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[15_0][0][publishedfileid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[17_0][0][appid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[17_0][0][title]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[17_0][1][appid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[17_0][1][title]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[17_0][2][appid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[17_0][2][title]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[17_0][3][appid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[17_0][3][title]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[17_0][4][appid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[17_0][4][title]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[17_0][5][appid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[17_0][5][title]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[17_0][6][appid]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rgShowcaseConfig[17_0][6][title]"


-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="type"

showcases
-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sessionID"

3c2744810f83032ad6072bda
-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"

1
-----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860--
```

Comment: можно начать с начала: что вы собираетесь сделать, каким кодом это реализовано, что не так и как должно быть?

Comment: @Jack_oS он хочет собрать тело как в примере

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для передачи дублирующихся ключей в form-data есть 2 способа:

```
>>> urllib.parse.urlencode((('a',1),('a',2)))
'a=1&a=2'

>>> urllib.parse.urlencode({'a':[1,2]},doseq=True)
'a=1&a=2'
```

По аналогии для multipart сработало

```
response = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", files=(('a',(None,'1')),('a',(None,2))))
```

Создаешь итератор (массив или кортеж) в формате `(имя,(имяфайла, контент))` и передаешь через параметр files

Пример

```
 -----------------------------26945955324554554721766291860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profile_showcase[]"

8
```

будет

```
("profile_showcase[]",(None, 8))
```